# Windows Remote Desktop with multiple monitors

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a remote desktop product that will allow me to switch on the fly between how many monitors the desktop is using. This would be going from one Windows 7 machine to another, one is running Ultimate, the other Enterprise.

I know I can use Windows RDP with multi-monitor support, but it seems that only allows me to use ALL monitors, and if I switch to a windowed view, I get huge scrollbars because I'm going from 3 monitors to 1 window.

What I'm looking for is something that will allow me to switch from 1, 2, or 3 monitor displays without restarting the RDP and would end up with a true 1/2/3 display - ie, if I go from 3 monitors to 1, or a window, I don't get scrollbars.

Is there any such product?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/default.aspx) Free. It allows me to switch between monitors...

Comment: LogMeIn doesn't appear to support multi-monitors unless both machines are physically connected to multiple monitors. In my case, the remote computer is a laptop, and only has one screen.

Comment: I remote into my home PC which has 2 monitor from my Netbook and others all the time...I can view either screen with a simple click!